# iOS Swift UITextfield adjust fontsize width

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How to adjust UITextfield font size when it is hold long character?
I tried adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth. it is not working.
any help will be appricated.thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to adjust font size according to width?

Answer (score 8):

With a UITextField, text must fit on one line and cannot wrap.

You have two options:

Shrink the font to fit on one line:

```
self.TextFieldExample.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; 
self.TextFieldExample.minimumFontSize = 10.0; //Optionally specify min size
```

Use UITextView to enable text wrapping:

Comment: Sorry I haven't work on swift but at least you will get some logic for Swift..Sorry again :)

Answer (score 4):

**Working Swift 4 Solution**

Make sure you set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to `true` and then set your `minimumFontSize`. This will scale the text inside the `UITextField` to fit the width of your `UITextField` with a minimum font size equal to or greater than what you set `minimumFontSize` to. When the text is still too long to scale down to fit at the minimum font size it will truncate the rest.

```
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
textField.minimumFontSize = 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the width first

```
textField.frame = CGRect(0, 0, your width, your height)
```

And

```
textField.minimumFontSize = 0.5
```

Comment: You need to set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to `true` in order to set the `minimumFontSize `.